# SQL Query to find the Max count with same email domain

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a email id column which stores the full email ID.
I want to get the maximum count based on the domain i.e @gmail.com,@xyz.com
Seems like in GROUP BY clause we cannot apply any wildcards which will only consider the domain from the full email address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMail.EMail, '@', -1) AS `Email Domain`, COUNT(*)
FROM EMail
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMail.EMail, '@', -1)
```

with data example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMail.EMail, '@', -1) AS `Email Domain`, COUNT(*)
FROM
  (
  select 'tuhin@gmail.com' as EMail
  UNION
    SELECT 'tuhin@yahoo.com'
    union
    select 'abc@xyz.com'
    union
      select 'hin@gmail.com'
  ) as EMail

  GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(EMail.EMail, '@', -1)
```

For SQL server

```
SELECT RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) Domain ,
COUNT(Email) EmailCount
FROM   dbo.email
WHERE  LEN(Email) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
ORDER BY EmailCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks.Worked like a charm

Comment: @souvikc as it is worked so please check the accept answer option